# Can't get a PowerKVM guest's network to work

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

I've been stuck by this issue for a couple of days. I am running a Ubuntu 14.04 guest on top of a PowerKVM host (PowerKVM is KVM on IBM's Power Systems, so basically it's just KVM.). I can't get the bridged network to work. I can't even ping the default gateway. My guess is that there's something wrong in the XML configuration file.

Here are the files.

**KVM Host**

```
    localhost:/root # ifconfig -a
    brenP3p5s0f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 172.16.229.200  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 172.16.229.255
         inet6 fe80::42f2:e9ff:fe5d:61bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 40:f2:e9:5d:61:bb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 40709  bytes 3013319 (2.8 MiB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 38  bytes 6015 (5.8 KiB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    enP3p5s0f0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 40:f2:e9:5d:61:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 252  

    enP3p5s0f1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 40:f2:e9:5d:61:b9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 253  

    enP3p5s0f2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.229.199  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 172.16.229.255
        inet6 fe80::42f2:e9ff:fe5d:61ba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 40:f2:e9:5d:61:ba  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 36345  bytes 4200608 (4.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23689  bytes 12817261 (12.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 252  

    enP3p5s0f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::42f2:e9ff:fe5d:61bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 40:f2:e9:5d:61:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32473  bytes 2927091 (2.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3080  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 364  bytes 78478 (76.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 253  

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 108802  bytes 28022560 (26.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 108802  bytes 28022560 (26.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


    virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:7b:a3:23  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    virbr1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.121.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.121.255
        ether 52:54:00:1e:11:18  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:7b:a3:23  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    virbr1-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:1e:11:18  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Host's Routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.229.193  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enP3p5s0f2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 enP3p5s0f2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1039   0        0 brenP3p5s0f3
172.16.229.192  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 enP3p5s0f2
172.16.229.192  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 brenP3p5s0f3
192.168.121.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

The guest's XML file (interface part) saved in the Host.

```
localhost:/root # virsh edit ubuntu01

<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:b8:bd:eb'/>
  <source bridge='brenP3p5s0f3'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

The Bridged Network XML file saved in the Host:

```
localhost:/root # cat /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/bridged.xml

<network>
  <name>bridged</name>
  <uuid>01ebaa45-0034-4a3f-8d57-fe67e03130b6</uuid>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='brenP3p5s0f3'/>
</network>
```

**Guest**

I can't copy/paste because I can't ssh (given that it's unreachable) and the console on virsh somehow doesn't work. However, when I start the VM I see no ip address defined. Then what I did is the following:

```
ifconfig eth0 172.16.229.201 netmask 255.255.255.192 up
ip route add default via 172.16.229.193
```

The default gw is the same also for the Host. The netmask I use is the same both for the guest and the host.

PROBLEM: when I ping the default gateway, I get the error "Destination Host Unreachable". When I ping myself 172.16.229.201, I can successfully ping.

One Update: a funny behavior happens when trying to tcpdump the IP Address of the default gw: I get sometihng like:

```
ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.6 tell 10.10.10.105, length 46
ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.6 tell 10.10.10.102, length 46
ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.252 tell 10.10.10.253, length 46
IP 10.10.10.2.1985 > 224.0.0.102.1985: HSRPv1
```

Multiple lines like that. I have no idea where it takes those IP addresses from. The "funny" thing is that I get the same output by tcpdump'ing the bridge interface on the Host! So it looks like tcpdump is accessing the network somehow from the guest! Otherwise I can't explain why the lines are the same. I want to stress that those private IP Addresses starting with 10 are not assigned anywhere in my subnet.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!